# Angular is not defined error

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, plunker

I am trying to create a login page and I have the html looking how I want it so now I am trying to create a controller but for some reason the js controller isnt working with the html. here is the plunker. The {{name}} data bind should display world but it isnt. Here is the controller:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

    app.controller('LoginController', function($scope) {
        $scope.name = 'World';
    });

})();
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/mqc6ksw1xo7NMhj74Noa?p=preview

Comment: you need to add angularjs file prior to use `angular.`

Comment: @vinayakj they did, but the link is not valid

Comment: In the head of my html file I add the angularjs before i add the app.js script... is that what you mean?

Comment: @TimCastelijns it didnt got downloaded, thats what I meant, cause OP has error _Angular is not defined_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is your angularjs link is not working , just replace with this,

```
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
```

**[`Working code`](http://plnkr.co/edit/YpgtaH6jDS9DLXLpPWi1?p=preview)**

Comment: `data-semver="2.0.0-alpha.31"`doesn't really apply anymore then

Comment: @TimCastelijns yes :)

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong link so it can't load angular, change

```
https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular.js
```

to

```
https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular2.js
```

note the extra '2' at the end